# How to get formatted text from RichTextBox and show it to TextBlock in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Following code is just **not** returning formatted text.

```
string StringFromRichTextBox(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        rtb.Document.ContentStart, 
        rtb.Document.ContentEnd
    );

    return textRange.Text;
}
```

I want to get formatted text and show it on `TextBlock` in `wpf`.

Comment: what do you want to foramt?

Comment: If text is bold then how to get that text with tag of bold?

Comment: RichTextBox and TextBLock don't mark up the same way.  It is not going to be a that easy.